# Why RelativeLayout keeps messing its inner layout while its height is set to WRAP_CONTENT?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with which wraps around an ImageView and 2 TextViews. The problem here is when I set the height of it to `wrap_content` one of the TextViews overlaps the other while it's set to reside under it but I set the height to a specific dp (like `56dp`) it's fine. Please refer to the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/new_profile_avatar"/>

    <com.imnumbers.newpkg.widget.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:text="Hamed Momeni"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:text="+989888898885"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also included screenshots to illustrate the problem.

Screenshot of how it looks:
[image: Wrong]

Screenshot of how it *should* look:
[image: Right]

Comment: Please remove the **+** signs from the below, toRight, toLeft, toEnd, ... id **references**. `@+id/avatar` => `@id/avatar`. Obviously NOT when assigning the id.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Didn't make any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for `name`, `android:layout_below="@+id/name"` for `number` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `RelativeLayout` created interdependency and result in error

Suggested fixes:

1. Remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for `name`, you may add marginTop for `name` to move it down a bit, e.g. `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`; or
2. Set fixed height for `RelativeLayout`, i.e. `android:layout_height="36dp"`

Comment: Nope, replaced all views with their built in versions to no avail.

Comment: Please check my edit, believe this is the actual cause

Comment: Your edit actually and obviously fixes the issue. But I wanted to avoid putting any value for margins and height but it seems there is no way around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `RelativeLayout` height to `"match_parent"`  i.e `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: I don't want it to fill its parent. I just need as big as its content. It's gonna be used in a RecyclerView.

Comment: you will inflate this layout in your view (`listview`) right?

Comment: Yes, it's inflated inside onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: Did try it. Still the same as `wrap_content`.